# How to copy char * to an array of 16 bytes

Tags: c++

How to copy char * to an array of 16 bytes.

```
const char *SK = "1234456789999978";
sample_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t alice[16];

memcpy(alice, (sample_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t*)SK, 16); //gives error
```

Definition of sample_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t

> typedef uint8_t sample_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t[16];

**Error:**
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 memcpy(alice, (sample_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t*)SK, 16);

Comment: 1) What error?  2) Why are you casting `SK` in the argument to `memcpy`?

Comment: What error does it give? It should work without any casts.

Comment: Why is your typedef different from what you use?

Comment: Looks like you are using C++ compiler. Also I have a feeling that this code is outside of a function block. Post [mcve].

Comment: @Eugene Yes I am using g++

Comment: *Why* are you using C++ compiler for C ?

Comment: with that typedef, does that mean `alice` is essentially a 16x16 array?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why do you think it is `C`? It's all perfectly legal `C++`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: @Galik Because it was originally tagged as C.

Comment: How to solve this problem in C++

Comment: Look again at Eugene's comment again.  It contains a possible reason for your problem.  And follow through with that MCVE.

Comment: This compiles fine at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WfihwpgsyRjLFGqO) **on C++11 and up** (I have taken out the unnecessary and irrelevant cast).  It's wrong (`alice` is an array of arrays and I'm sure you don't mean that), but it compiles.

Comment: Interesting, my g++ compiler fails to compile. May be because some compiler flags.
But I got the answer for these comments.

Comment: imho array typedefs are nasty because they hide the decay to pointer, for example in `void foo(sample_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t x);`  `x` is not what one might it expect to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    typedef int sgx_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t;
    const char *SK = "1234456789999978";
    sgx_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t alice[16];
    std::copy(SK, SK + strlen(SK), alice);
    for(auto& i : alice){
        std::cout << i - '0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Take care that your `typedef` name matches the name you use. (It didn't in question.) And you can remove the cast to `sgx_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t`. Hopefully this accomplishes what you're trying to do.

Comment: The program is a C++ program.

Comment: Then why did you tag it [c]?

Comment: You should tag C++ instead of C, in that case.

Comment: Done, Corrected

Comment: Annabelle, I think you mean `typedef **uint_8** sgx_aes_gcm_128bit_key_t`.  And that `printf` needs a terminating `nul`.

Comment: For C++, change `memcpy` to `std::copy`.  Change `printf` to use `cout`.  Or leave it alone and change `#include <stdio.h>` to `#include <cstdio>`.

Comment: @RoshanMehta You tagged it incorrectly at time of post.

Comment: Regardless, @RoshanMehta I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use memcpy with C++, that is fully possible. Inside memcpy you should use casts to **(void*)**

```
memcpy((void*)alice, (void*)SK, 16);
```

Make sure to get types and size right to prevent segmentation fault.

Comment: Didn't need the `void *`casts: https://ideone.com/eMpCQT

Comment: It probably has to do with the IDE. Anyway if it works like that, the question has no need for an answer. When the compiler gives errors, a cast fixes it.

Comment: To those who wander in later and don't already know this, the C-Style cast can also be used to lie to the compiler and tell it that the square peg fits in the round hole, causing logic errors later. It should be viewed with maximum caution and only be used when you know you are correct and all other options have been exhausted. In other words  almost never.

Comment: Yup. It is also a great feature when used with proper understanding